# Getting error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" on .JSON file

Tags: google-chrome

When i Link a JSON file to an HTML file i get this error, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "Names": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test Name 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Test Name 2"
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately questions regarding [coding](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic for this site. You might ask this over at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to review the FAQ in their Help Center first.

Answer (score 1):

> When i Link a JSON file to an HTML file

HTML provides no real standard mechanism for doing that.

The error message you are getting suggests that you are attempting:

```
<script src="myjson.json"></script>
```

JSON is a data format, not a JavaScript program, so you can't use a script element to source it.

The usual approach is to use the `XMLHttpRequest` object from JavaScript.

```
<script>
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "myjson.json");
  xhr.addEventListener('load', processJSON);
  xhr.send();

  function processJSON(event) {
    var json = this.responseText;
    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
    // and do something with obj here
  }
</script>
```